# Saving textarea with breaks, MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, mern

How do I save a multiple paragraph in MongoDB I have a textarea that allows to input multiple paragraphs but doesn't save the line space in the data base

**For example, I want the submitted data to be like this**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, sequi? Lorem ipsum dolor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, sequi?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, sequi? Lorem ipsum dolor

**but it saves like this**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, sequi? Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, sequi? Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, sequi? Lorem ipsum dolor

Answer (score 0):

make sure your text is inside a `<pre>` tag so it will preserve the formatting

Comment: The problem with this it keeps it a single line until  u indicate the line break, like I have a 4 lines of a single paragraph, it just renders 1 line on the browser.

Comment: your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608841/how-do-i-store-display-paragraphs-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

With @Patrik Gohil's comment I was able to use the nl2br, since I am using a react the nl2br packaged didn't work but I used another packaged called [link](https://github.com/yosuke-furukawa/react-nl2br), since in react we need to create an element thru javascript